# Meaning of a discrete topological sub-space?

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $X$ and a set $U\subseteq X$, what is the meaning of $U$ being a *discrete sub-space* of $X$?

I do know what a discrete space is, so as far as I understand it, the meaning is that each $A\subseteq U$ is open in the relative topology in $U$? And if I understand it correctly, given $U$ is open in $X$, will this apply that $A$ is open in $X$ as well?

Please fix me if I'm wrong, just wanted to make sure I understand it correctly.

Comment: +1 I can't think of anything else. That is a strong indication, but it sure makes sense to ask questions like this anyhow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the subspace topology on $U$  induced by $X$ is the same topology as the discrete topology.

Yes, if $U$ is open in $X$ and $A$ is open in $U$ then $A$ is open in $X$.

"I do know what a discrete space is, so as far as I understand it, the meaning is that each $A\subseteq U$ is open in the relative topology in $U$"

Yes, the subspace topology (or relative topology) means that $A \subseteq U$ is open if and only if there is an open set $O$ in $X$ such that $O \cap U = A$.

The discrete topology is the topology where every set is open. This is induced by the discrete metric.

Consider the set $U=\mathbb Z$ in $X=\mathbb R$. Then $U$ endowed with the subspace topology is a discrete space, in particular, every singleton $\{k\}$ is open in the subspace topology. Of course this is false for the set $\{k\} \subseteq \mathbb R$.

Comment: "No, and I don't understand what the sentence means."
I mean that every $A\subseteq U$ is open in the topology on $U$ induced by $X$? Or else what does the word 'discrete' mean?

Comment: @Eric_ Yes, that's right. And sorry, I couldn't make sense of it before.

Answer (score 4):

Basicaly right. An example will be helpful fou you.

Let $X=\Bbb R$ with usual topology. And Let $U=\Bbb N=\{1,2,\cdots,n\cdots\}$. Then $U$ is a subspace of $X$ with discrete topology.

If $U$ is open in $X$ and $A$ is open in $U$, $A$ is open in $X$ indeed!

Comment: Duh, beat me by 52 seconds and I didn't even get a notification that someone else posted an answer.

Comment: @MattN. Hahahaha